# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-rJRUpL/pyfinite/

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install pyfinite using

> pip install pyfinite

but when I try that I get the following error:

```
    Collecting pyfinite
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ca/d3/c836cdb45006961c7917572d9673a0bd9e9e241df264cccca96cbbca1221/pyfinite-1.7.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-rJRUpL/pyfinite/setup.py", line 30, in <module>
        long_description=get_readme(),
      File "/tmp/pip-install-rJRUpL/pyfinite/setup.py", line 21, in get_readme
        with open(path.join(here, 'README.rst'), encoding='utf-8') as my_fd:
    TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-rJRUpL/pyfinite/
```

I re-installed pip but that did not solve my problem although I executed the pip command with sudo and that did not solve my problem.

My operation system is ubuntu 18.04

what is wrong? how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

[pyfinite is Python3-only](https://github.com/emin63/pyfinite/blob/dff936523be68f8c0c98f0481aa3a109f067b7da/setup.py#L39), it doesn't work with Python 2.7.

Comment: so it only works with pip3 install pyfinite?
but in the official website they used pip not pip3

Comment: If one installs only Python3, there is no need to name `pip` as `pip3`. The distinction between `pip` and `pip3` is important to distinguish `pip` for Python2 and `pip` for Python3. Also in a virtualenv the script is called `pip` regardless of the Python version.